# Partial derivatives of implicit functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

So, I have an implicit expression for a change of variables from Cartesian to a different system using $u$ and $v$.

This is given by:

$G(x,y,z,u,v)=0$, $F(x,y,z,u,v)=0$, where $F$, $G$, $u=f(x,y,z)$ and $v=g(x,y,z)$ are all differentiable.

Differentiating F, say, we get:

$\frac{dF}{dx} = \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}} + \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{u}} \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} + \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{v}}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}$

My questions:

Is this because you have $\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{x}} = 1$, and  $\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} = 0$?

This seems like an obvious question but I don't really understand where the $ \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}$ term is coming from, or why is just appears here. For example if we had $f(x,y,z)=f(x(t), y(t), z(t))$, if we wanted to differentiate that with respect to t we wouldn't have an $ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{t}}$ term.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the chain rule.

Perhaps it's easier to see if you rename things a little, so that you don't use the same symbols for the coordinates as for the functions involved.

If from the function $F(x,y,z,u,v)$ you form the composed function
$$
f(r,s,t)=F\bigl(X(r,s,t),Y(r,s,t),Z(r,s,t),U(r,s,t),V(r,s,t)\bigr)
,
$$
then the chain rule says that
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(r,s,t)
&=
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\bigl(X(r,s,t),Y(r,s,t),Z(r,s,t),U(r,s,t),V(r,s,t)\bigr) \frac{\partial X}{\partial r}(r,s,t)
\\ &+
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\bigl(X(r,s,t),Y(r,s,t),Z(r,s,t),U(r,s,t),V(r,s,t)\bigr) \frac{\partial Y}{\partial r}(r,s,t)
\\ &+
\cdots
\\ &+
\cdots
\\ &+
\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\bigl(X(r,s,t),Y(r,s,t),Z(r,s,t),U(r,s,t),V(r,s,t)\bigr) \frac{\partial V}{\partial r}(r,s,t)
.
\end{split}
$$
In your case you have
$$
X(r,s,t)=r
,\quad
Y(r,s,t)=s
,\quad
Z(r,s,t)=t
$$
and
$$
U(r,s,t)=f(r,s,t)
,\quad
V(r,s,t)=g(r,s,t)
.
$$
Then $\partial X/\partial r=1$ and $\partial Y/\partial r=\partial Z/\partial r=0$, so you're left with
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(r,s,t)
&=
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\bigl(X(r,s,t),Y(r,s,t),Z(r,s,t),U(r,s,t),V(r,s,t)\bigr)
\\ &+
\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\bigl(X(r,s,t),Y(r,s,t),Z(r,s,t),U(r,s,t),V(r,s,t)\bigr) \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(r,s,t)
\\ &+
\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\bigl(X(r,s,t),Y(r,s,t),Z(r,s,t),U(r,s,t),V(r,s,t)\bigr) \frac{\partial g}{\partial r}(r,s,t)
,
\end{split}
$$
which is the formula that you asked about, in slightly different notation.